# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets) in tower of hanoi

Tags: haskell

This my program problem is occurring when I load this file:

```
hanoi :: Integer -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move]
hanoi 0 _ _ _ = []
hanoi n a b c =
let 
step1move = hanoi (n-1) a c b
step2move = (a,b)
step3move = hanoi (n-1) c b a
in
step1move ++ [step2move] ++ step3move`

hanoi4 :: Integer -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move]
hanoi4 0 _ _ _ _ = []
hanoi4 n a b c d =
let 
(half1,half2) = segment n
step1 = hanoi4 half1 a c b d
step2 = hanoi half2 a d b
step3 = (a, b)
step4 = hanoi half2 d b a
step5 = hanoi4 half1 c b a d
in
step1 ++ step2 ++ [step3] ++ step4 ++ step5

-- Segment n into two "halves" such that half1 + half2 = n - 1
segment :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
segment n = let half1 = n div 2 in (half1, n half1=1)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues.  First, your function definitions need to be indented.  (Unlike most C-family languages that use curly braces and semicolons, Haskell's parser uses whitespace to define the bodies of functions and other syntactic constructs like do-blocks.)  So instead of:

```
hanoi n a b c =
let
...
```

you need:

```
hanoi n a b c =
  let
  ..
```

Second, you have two stray backtick (`) characters.

Third, your `segment` function definition looks like it's got some wrong characters in it:

```
-segment n = let half1 = n div 2 in (half1, n half1=1)`
+segment n = let half1 = n div 2 in (half1, n-half1-1)
```